# AspNet Core CORS doesnt work when Session is enabled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("mypolicy",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    builder.AllowCredentials();
                });
            });

app.UseCors("mypolicy");

[HttpGet("")]
public object Index(string hello)
{
  this.HttpContext.Session.SetString("hello", hello);
  return new {data = "Connected to API"};
}
```

Http Get request to the Index method errors with

**'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'**

while the origin is clearly allowed in the CORS configuration, what the heck microsoft !??, it works tho if i remove the Session.SetString line

Comment: Make sure your code doesn't **throw any exceptions**. Exceptions are caught by the `UseExceptionHandler`/ `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` middleware. When this happens, the **headers are cleared**, which also means, that the CORS headers set by the `UseCors` middleware are cleared too, and this results in browser rejecting the request due to same origin policy violation. So before doing a **rant** here, you should get familiar on how the ASP.NET Core pipeline works to avoid misunderstandings and accuse the wrong people for that

Comment: lol, i got them already, i see no exceptions at all, plus the code works properly when im accessing the page from its own origin (sent frontend from webapi), something definitely clears the headers, no info left in kestrel logs too, the entire asp.net is all black pandora box

Comment: And have you ensure that the cookie is set before you request it for the first time? If no cookie is there, the session middleware needs to set the cookie in order to identify the session on next call.  Using Sessions in a stateless service (WebApi is primary for REST services, which should be stateless) is a bad idea anyways. All data required for a request should be sent with the request, that's what REST service is about

Answer (score 0):

If I take your code and put it into a new 1.1 project, the response will use Set-Cookie to start a new session and add CORs headers (see curl session below, with some headers omitted). Something else must be going wrong.

```
> curl -i --header "Origin: http://foo.com" http://localhost:4354/

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Kestrel
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Session=CfDJ8DI5n6m4L...; path=/; httponly
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.com
```